# EsLint: unexpected token '('

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, eslint

EsLint pull this error:

**error  Parsing error: Unexpected token (**

from this line of code:

```
let fn = () => {
            //stuffs...
        }();  //<---- THIS
```

The code obviously works well, so what is the issue?

Comment: _"The code obviously works well"_ Does it? Have you actually used it? In what environment?

Comment: @JLRishe of course i did

Comment: It doesn't work in Chrome. Chrome gives the same error.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mention that i'm actually transpiling it with babel-loader